# improve function to highlight all types of search terms - react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, search

I am running a React Native app. I have a SearchBar that highlights the text in the search results.

[image]

Code:

```
Highlight(fullText, searchTerm){   //Highlight function
  if (!searchTerm.trim()) {
    return <Text>{fullText}</Text>
  }
  const regex = new RegExp(`(${_.escapeRegExp(searchTerm)})`, 'gi')
  const parts = fullText.split(regex)
  let final = parts.filter(part => part).map((part, i) => regex.test(part) ?
      <Text style={{backgroundColor: 'coral'}} key={i}>{part}</Text>
     : <Text key={i}>{part}</Text>
  )
  return (
    <Text>{final}</Text>
  )
}






render(){

<Text> this.Hightlight(text, search) </Text>

}
```

But this Highlight function doesn't work for the below search term.
I typed **"ha mess"** but neither **"ha"** nor **"mess"** was highlighted.

[image]

I want the text to be highlighted even when its not consecutive. 
How can i tweak the highlight function to achieve this??

Expected result is something like below. Everything gets highlighted irrespective of the order of words.

[image]

Comment: so you need to highlight ha and mess separately?

Comment: yes. whatever i type needs to be highlighted irrespective of the order of words.

Comment: @Apostolos check my updated question. i have added expected result.

Comment: so if you type "lo do" and text has "falo dobava" it should highlight "lo do" along with empty space? or just lo and do separately?

Comment: @Apostolos it should highlight "lo" "do" separately no empty spaces.

Comment: yudu gave the answer, was a bit quicker :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to split the `searchTerm` with spaces.

```js
const regexStr = "(" + searchTerm.trim().split(/\s+/).map(escapeRegExp).join("|") + ")";
const regex = new RegExp(regexStr, "gi");
```

Live demo available at: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-pascal-4trrk?file=/src/App.js:419-460

Comment: Thanks man. But this is causing white space issue. When i type "ha " (ha with space), the entire text "ha general message" gets highlighted.

Comment: @grooot sorry, forget to trim searchTerm, fixed.